# Download a file from AWS S3 with Angular 2+

Tags: asp.net, angular, amazon-s3

I have an ASP.NET Core web app and I'm using Angular 4. There are a lot of resources showing how to upload a file to S3, which I've done. But there doesn't seem to be anything about reading the file.

I want to give users the ability to upload a JSON file, save it to S3, then on a different view show the user all of the files they've uploaded as well as display the content of the file.

Are there any resources for showing how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If its publicaly available items, you can use the [S3 JavaScript SDKs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property) 'getObject' method to download a file.

```
/* The following example retrieves an object for an S3 bucket. */

 var params = {
  Bucket: "examplebucket", 
  Key: "HappyFace.jpg"
 };
 s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /*
   data = {
    AcceptRanges: "bytes", 
    ContentLength: 3191, 
    ContentType: "image/jpeg", 
    ETag: "\"6805f2cfc46c0f04559748bb039d69ae\"", 
    LastModified: <Date Representation>, 
    Metadata: {
    }, 
    TagCount: 2, 
    VersionId: "null"
   }
   */
 });
```

If the files are private, use [S3 Signed Urls](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) or [CloudFront Signed Urls](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html)( or Cookies) to generate a download Url from your backend after authorizing the user. Using this download url, download the file from S3 directly in angular app.

Examples:

- Using [CloudFront signed](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateCFSignatureCodeAndExamples.html) urls.
- Using [S3 Signed Url](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) using the S3 SDKs getSignedUrl method.

Another option is to generate S3 temporary access credentials from AWS STS directly from your backend and send back to the Angular app or using a authentication service such as AWS Cognito so that Angular app can use it to invoke the S3 SDK.